# Cloudflare: purge of single files doesn't work

Tags: http-headers, cloudflare

I am trying to purge the homepage of my site (and only the homepage) and I am not succeeding. Hurl.it keeps being served a "hit". To test things further, I opened the Cloudflare interface, and added the following two lines in the "Purge individual files" field on the caching tab, which basically is a manual purge of the homepage (or so I think)

https://example.com/
https://example.com

But still the same thing:

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400
Cf-Cache-Status: HIT
Cf-Ray: 3222f7c328d90862-IAD
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 16 Jan 2017 16:33:12 GMT
Expires: Tue, 17 Jan 2017 16:33:12 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 16 Jan 2017 16:11:40 GMT
Pragma:
Server: cloudflare-nginx
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d936c80f83c1f69774f457a1f85937d141484584392; expires=Tue, 16-Jan-18 16:33:12 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Anyone an idea why this is the case? Something in the headers?

Comment: By default CloudFlare does not cache html. Do you have a custom rule set up?

Comment: Yes, I have. Although I am now looking into the problem that it might be Chrome that is messing with me...

Comment: What is your webserver running? apache? nginx? What version? It seems that Pragma Header is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your browser is caching the response; I note the Cache-Control header is set to a few hours. Cloudflare will, by default, override Cache-Control headers - you can however bypass this behaviour using a feature known as "Respect Existing Headers".

In order to utilise this - firstly navigate to the caching tab in the Cloudflare dashboard.

[image: Cloudflare Caching Tab]

Once here, scroll down to an option labelled "Browser Cache Expiration", simply select the "Respect Existing Headers" option here. After this is set, Cloudflare will not override Cache-Control headers (even if they don't exist at all).

[image: Respect Existing Headers Cloudflare]

For more information:

- [What does browser cache expire TTL mean?](https://cloudflare.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168366)
- [How do I cache static HTML?](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172256-How-do-I-cache-static-HTML-)

Comment: Nice! I already noticed that it was the browser cache. Will try your solution.